# Probability Density Function and Proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, operations-research

Given the Probability Density Function: $f(x)=kx(2-x), 0\leq x\leq 1$
Prove that $k=\frac 3 2$

Looks like it should be a Beta Distribution, but all examples of a beta distribution use the format: $f(x)=kx^{(a-1)}(1-x)^{(b-1)}, 0\leq x\leq 1$ where $k=\frac {(a-b-1)!}{(a-1)!(b-1)!}$

Comment: You wish to find $k$ such that: $\int_0^1 kx(2-x)\;\mathrm{d}x = 1$

Comment: So, do you want to find this constant or to classify the pdf?

Comment: Show that the constant k is 3/2 in such a way that we can then continue on to find the Mean and Variance. I just need to know how to adjust k=(a−b−1)!/(a−1)!(b−1)! so that k is equal to 3/2 while both a and b are equal to 2

Comment: Hint: It is *not* a beta distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\begin{cases}kx(2-x) &: 0\leq x\leq 1\\ 0 &: \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Since $f(x)$ is a probability density function then: $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x = 1$

So for the given function you will need to find $k$ such that: $\int\limits_0^1 kx(2-x)\;\mathrm{d}x = 1$

$$\therefore f(x) = \frac 32 x(2-x), 0\leq x\leq 1$$

Mean: $\displaystyle \bar X = \operatorname{E}[X] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x = \frac 32 \int_0^1 2x^2-x^3\;\mathrm{d}x$

Variance: $\displaystyle \operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2]-\operatorname{E}[X]^2 =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x - (\bar X)^2  = \frac 32 \int_0^1 2x^3-x^4\;\mathrm{d}x-(\bar X)^2$

Comment: I actually need to show that $k=3/2=(a−b−1)!/(a−1)!(b−1)!$ or something similar

Comment: @Sasha No, it's not a beta distribution.